# python's requests showing weird language instead of arabic

Tags: python, python-requests

I am making a python script, and I want it to get an Arabin text from the site, but when I use requests to get the text all I get is:

> æóæÇÌóÒóÚÇð áóæ ßÇäó áöáäóÝÓö ãóÌÒóÚõ

instead of this:

> اذا ما مَشَت نادى بما في ثِيابها
>   ذكِيُّ الشذا والمَندَليّ المطَيَّرُ

I tried the same code on different site that also uses Arabic, and the code worked perfectly and grabbed the Arabic text without any problems

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

a = requests.get("https://www.aldiwan.net/poem30.html")
a = a.text
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is

Comment: my question  is how do i grab "اذا ما مَشَت نادى بما في ثِيابها ذكِيُّ الشذا والمَندَليّ المطَيَّرُ" instead of 
"æóæÇÌóÒóÚÇð áóæ ßÇäó áöáäóÝÓö ãóÌÒóÚõ"

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example of what works (as you mentioned something that works) and what doesn't works

Comment: if you use requests.get on this site https://4byt.com/most-viewed, you will get arabin text, but if you used this on this site https://www.aldiwan.net/poem30.html you will face the same issue as me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decode a.content not a.text

I tried decoding it using utf-8, but it kept failing, so I went over to the url, they were using a specific type of charset, which is windows-1256.

[image]

I  used that same thing to decode a.content, and voila!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

a = requests.get("https://www.aldiwan.net/poem30.html")
a = a.content.decode('utf-8')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).